# How to call a variable from other file in python?

Tags: python, selenium, automation

I have created 2 files.
a.py has a class foo() and b.py has a class fun(). fun() is a child class of foo().
foo() has a function given below:

```
def get_random_password(self):
    " func to generate random password "
    try:
        password_characters = string.ascii_letters + string.digits + string.punctuation
        nw_password = ''.join(random.choice(password_characters) for i in range(30))
        return nw_password
```

now i want to use this nw_password variable in some other function of fun() ( given below function is used for user login)

```
        username = self.driver.find_element_by_id("username")
        time.sleep(3)
        username.send_keys(self.vm_spec_dic['name'])
        time.sleep(5)
        password = self.driver.find_element_by_id("password")
        time.sleep(5)
        password.send_keys(nw_password)
        time.sleep(10)
        login = self.driver.find_element_by_id("loginBtn")
        login.click()
```

I am using selenium to automate. I want to call variable nw_password from a.py to b.py. but getting error? I am getting errors like module 'lib.b' has no attribute 'nw_password' ????

```
from a import nw_password
```

Importing is not working

Comment: variables inside a try statement are enclosed by their own block

Comment: He's saying he can't even import though

Comment: What's your project structure?

Comment: Also as the answer below shows you for this line `password.send_keys(nw_password)` you need to call the `nw_password` function: `password.send_keys(nw_password())`

Comment: Oishin please update the question with the error you're having on importing. Maybe `a` is the name of something in the python standard library you may have to rename the file

Comment: @RolvApneseth I am using selenium to automate for ui-testing. I am trying to generate a random password for user login... soo in first function i am generating password and storing in variable nw_password and later using it to get login to user in another function.

Comment: I see the issue now sorry for misunderstanding

Answer (score 0):

The scope of the variable is only inside the function definition, you could probably use a variable and store the return of the get_random_password(self) method

`var = yourObjectFromfoo.get_random_password()`

then try to import that var

Comment: He's unable to import the module in the first place it seems

Comment: It's a bit vague, but he said (module 'lib.b' has no attribute 'nw_password'), so I thought he is having an issue with the variable not the module it self
In any way he can't import the variable that way even if the module could be imported

Comment: @oshinaggrawal are you getting an error importing?

Comment: @RolvApneseth yess.. it says no attribute

Comment: @MohammedEzzat Is calling nw_password as a global variable not possible across files ????

Comment: @Oshinaggrawal as it stands in your snippet, it's not global
the variable defined inside the scope of a method is only callable inside it, if you want it to be global you could either define nw_password with an initial value outside the class and then make your edits to it when you call the function. or more appropriate is to define a self.nw_password in your init, that will equal to the return of the function>>> like self.nw_password = self.get_random_password()

Comment: @MohammedEzzat Hey !! thanks a lot for your help.. that information was really helpful !!!

Answer (score 0):

To import your function try this:

```
from a import get_random_password
```

If you want to save it to a variable called `nw_password` you can do this in you main file:

```
nw_password = get_random_password()
```

`nw_password` is just the name of your returned value you're not storing it anywhere. So to get the random password you have to actually run the function you created. And as others have said the variable would be inside the function scope anyway so you would have to make it a global variable (not recommended).

Comment: To call just the value of `nw_password` from the file, inside a you would have to say, outside of the function, write: `nw_password = get_random_password()` then inside your main file you can now use `from a import nw_password`

Comment: from a import nw_password
ImportError: cannot import name 'nw_password' Getting error

Comment: Just do the top method where in you main file you import the function you made in `a`